# How can I select children of an element that has a specific class in Angular directive?

Tags: angular, image, css-selectors, directive

How can I select children of an element that has a specific class in Angular directive?

I am trying to intercept an image download error with the following directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '.imgs-container img',
    host: {
        '(error)': 'onImgError($event)'
    }
})
export class InterceptImgErrorDirective {
    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef
    ) {
        const sotp = 0;
    }

    onImgError(arg: any) {
        const stop = 0;
    }
}
```

Now in html I have:

```
<div class="imgs-container">
    <img>
</div>
```

I am expecting my breakpoint to come into the directive's constructor. But the breakpoint is never hit.

I tried to google and find something on the complex directive selectors, like the one I am using here. And I neither found that it is possible, nor did I find that it is impossible.

So, could someone advise me on the matter, please? Is it impossible or am I missing something here?

I am not interested in all the images on my page. I am only interested in the images which are contained in a specific `div`. So, I can not use just the `img` selector. Also, I can not apply a specific class to all the images inside the specific element. So, I can not use something like the `img.intercept-error-here` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question: is NOT possible to select children using the selector atrribute. In the angular documentation is written the following for the the directive selector:

> Angular only allows directives to apply on CSS selectors that do not cross element boundaries.

https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

Comment: If you want to test your directive's selector, you can try on : https://ydomenjoud.github.io/angular-selector-parser/

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't look like the selector handles CSS selectors for children. I tried reproducing this in stackblitz, and if the selector is

```
selector: '.imgs-container img',
```

the Directive constructor doesn't get called. meaning the Directive is never initialized, which is why your error isn't loading.

if I modify selector to target an element, and not it's children, it works. i.e.

```
selector: "img[src]",
```

then the constructor is called and the onError also fires. if the selector is `.imgs-container`, the constructor gets initialized as well.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbaep4?file=src/app/app.component.html) is a link for the `img[src]` selector

I would suggest modifying your selector to target an element and not children of an element

Comment: There are no selectors, which would target children of an element. Each selector targets a set of elements. Sorry, but your answer is not useful at all.